# Comparing almost paired data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I have gene expression measured for the same set of genes in 2 different conditions, but not all genes are measurable (NaN sometimes). This arises because I have the log-fold difference of expression relative to wild type, and clearly, log of zero is not defined.

Hence, the number of genes in the 2 conditions differs (by not much maybe 2%). I would like to ask what type of nonparametric statistical tests I can use to compare the distributions from the data in the 2 conditions.

There are paired tests and also tests requiring independent samples, but none of it is exactly my case.

Comment: How does the missingness arise? could it be related to the value of the response in any way for example?

Comment: I am taking log2-fold expression with respect to wt condition, so log2 of zero is not defined (that's why NaN).

Comment: This is important information to anyone attempting to give useful advice, please edit what you're doing there (and why you're doing that) into your question.